# MergJSON error "...unexpected token near end of file"?

Tags: json, livecode

I have the simplest of scripts in LiveCode attempting to parse a small chunk of JSON using the MergJSON library.

This is doubtless something stupid I'm doing as it's been a long day, but I just can't get the JSON parsed into a LiveCode array:

### LC Script in a button called 'Connect'

```
function JSONToArray pJSON
   local tArray,tKeys
   repeat for each line tKey in mergJSONDecode(pJSON,"tArray")
   put JSONToArray(tArray[tKey]) into tArray[tKey]
   end repeat
   return tArray
end JSONToArray

on mouseUp
   put field "MyJSON" into pJSON
   answer JSONToArray()
end mouseUp
```

### My JSON

```
{
"firstname":"Mary",
"lastname":"Smith",
}
```

### The Error:

*Button "Connect": execution error at line n/a (External handler: exception) near "could not decode JSON: unexpected token near end of file"*

Suggestions would be most welcome....

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Drop the comma after the last property in your JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark B might have it but the other thing could be that you're not passing the parameter to JSONToArray...

```
put JSONToArray(pJSON) into tArray
put tArray["firstname"]
```

Comment: Thanks both - it wasn't the danlging comma Mark & I'm still stuck Monte, is there any chance of you posting a snippet of LiveCode that grabs a bit of JSON from a field, parses it through MergJSON and Answers it back to screen? I should be able to grasp what's going on!  Thanks again, Steve

Comment: All figured now, the answer (from Monte!) was starring me in the face.  Thanks again Monte - on to my next question now!  :-)

Comment: OK, if my answer completely resolved the issue could you mark it as correct for the next user to see. If not could you create an answer yourself with the complete resolution.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"firstname":"Mary",
"lastname":"Smith",   <---dangling comma
}
```